# Display data from database in SINGLE dropdownlist

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, html-select

I have 1 goal which is to DISPLAY DATA from DATABASE in one SINGLE DROPDOWN LIST.

Right now in my database there are 3 data. I am able to display in 3 DROPDOWN LISTS which I do not know what. Is there a way to display in one dropdown list instead?

Below are my codes.

```
<c:forEach var="staff" items="${staff}">
<select name="staffId"><option value="${staff.staffId}">${staff.staffName}</option></select>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="staffId">
<c:forEach var="staff" items="${staff}">
<option value="${staff.staffId}">${staff.staffName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```